# I'm having problems with springboot 3.0.0 it doesn't recognize my eureka server and client

Tags: spring-boot, netflix-eureka

I have problems with springboot 3.0.0 it doesn't recognize my eureka server and client but in version 2.7.4 it works normally was there any change?

follow my classes:

api-gateway:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableEurekaServer
public class ApiGatewayApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ApiGatewayApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

application.properties:

```
spring.application.name = api-gateway
server.port = 8761
eureka.client.register-with-eureka = false
eureka.client.fetch-registry = false
eureka.instance.hostname=localhost
eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone=http://localhost:8761/eureka/
```

My routing:

```
@EnableDiscoveryClient
@SpringBootApplication
public class RoutingApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(RoutingApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

application.properties:

```
server.port=8080
spring.application.name=routing
eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone=http://localhost:8761/eureka/
eureka.instance.hostname=localhost
spring.cloud.gateway.discovery.locator.enabled=true

#spring.main.web-application-type=reactive
spring.cloud.gateway.enabled=true
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[0].id=user
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[0].uri=lb://USER
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[0].predicates=Path=/user/**

spring.cloud.gateway.routes[1].id=testes
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[1].uri=lb://TESTES
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[1].predicates=Path=/testes/**

spring.cloud.gateway.routes[2].id=user-create
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[2].uri=lb://USER-CREATE
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[2].predicates=Path=/user-create/**

spring.cloud.gateway.routes[3].id=category-product
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[3].uri=lb://CATEGORY-PRODUCT
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[3].predicates=Path=/category-product/**
```

My category-product

```
@EnableDiscoveryClient
@SpringBootApplication
public class CategoryProductApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(CategoryProductApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

My controller:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/category-product")
public class CategoryProductContriller {


  @GetMapping("/item")
  public String itens()
  {
    return "Testar";
  }

}
```

application.properties

```
    server.port = 8001
    spring.application.name = category-product
    eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone = http://localhost:8761/eureka

eureka.instance.hostname=localhost
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

same problems and the following changes worked for me.

On server side,in the pom.xml make these changes (`spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-server`):

```
<properties>
    <java.version>17</java.version>
    <spring-cloud.version>2022.0.0-RC2</spring-cloud.version>
</properties>
...   
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
...
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>netflix-candidates</id>
        <name>Netflix Candidates</name>
        <url>https://artifactory-oss.prod.netflix.net/artifactory/maven-oss-candidates</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>spring-milestones</id>
        <name>Spring Milestones</name>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

Same changes on client side (`spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client`) but in addition you have remove @EnableEurekaClient in *Application.java because `import org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.EnableEurekaClient` is not longer avaible.

I solved the problem by creating a new project from [Spring Initializr](https://start.spring.io/) and watching the dependecies in the pom.xml.
Currently I couldn't find any documentation about it.

Comment: The funny thing is eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone key is not even recognized. I am using cloud 2022.0.2

Answer (score 2):

I am using Java 17 and Spring Boot 3.0.5.

my configuration is the below:

application yaml ->

```
eureka:
  client:
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: https://eureka-server.com/eureka/
  instance:
    preferIpAddress: true
```

pom.xml ->

```
<dependencies>         
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>
       </dependency>
</dependencies>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>2022.0.3</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

Main class ->

```
@EnableDiscoveryClient
@SpringBootApplication
public class BlaBlaApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(BlaBlaApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```